# Tikz picture next to text in document

Tags: tikz-pgf, enumerate, minipage, text, pspicture

I'm using the minipage enviroment to try to put the eight 8th-roots of a complex numbers nexxt to a tikz figure that represents those roots like a regular octagon.

My code is:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\omega_8^0=\sqrt[8]{8} e^{-i\pi/24}$
\item $\omega_8^1=\sqrt[8]{8}e^{5i\pi /24}$
\item $\omega_8^2=\sqrt[8]{8}e^{11\pi i/24}$ 
\item $\omega_8^3=\sqrt[8]{8}e^{17\pi i/24}$ 
\item $\omega_8^4=\sqrt[8]{8}e^{23\pi i/24}$ 
\item $\omega_8^5=\sqrt[8]{8}e^{-19\pi i/24}$
\item $\omega_8^6=\sqrt[8]{8}e^{-13\pi i/24}$
\item $\omega_8^7=\sqrt[8]{8}e^{-7\pi i/24}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0) ;
\fill [black] (O) circle[radius=2pt];
\coordinate (A) at (0:3cm) ;
\coordinate (B) at (45:3cm) ;
\coordinate (C) at (90:3cm) ;
\coordinate (D) at (135:3cm) ;
\coordinate (E) at (180:3cm) ;
\coordinate (F) at (225:3cm) ;
\coordinate (G) at (270:3cm) ;
\coordinate (H) at (315:3cm) ;
\coordinate (Xm) at (-4,0) ;
\coordinate (Xp) at (4,0) ;
\coordinate (Ym) at (0,-4) ;
\coordinate (Yp) at (0,4) ;
\draw[gray, ->] (Xm) -- (Xp) node[right] {$\Re$};
\draw[gray, ->] (Ym) -- (Yp)node[right] {$\Im$} ;
\draw[orange, very thick] (O) circle(3cm) ;
\draw (O) node[left=20pt]
      node[above=10pt, right=18pt, olive!100] {$\frac{\pi}{4}$}
    -- (A) node[above right] {$\omega_8^0$} ;
\draw (B) node[above right=1.2pt] {$\omega_8^1$} -- (O)
   -- (C) node[above right] {$\omega_8^2$} ;
\draw (D) node[above left] {$\omega_8^3$} -- (O)
   -- (E) node[above left] {$\omega_8^4$} ;
   \draw (F) node[below left] {$\omega_8^5$} -- (O)
   -- (G) node[below left] {$\omega_8^6$} ;
\draw (H) node[below right] {$\omega_8^7$} -- (O) 
   -- (A) node[above right] ;
\draw[teal!80, thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- (F) -- (G) -- (H) -- cycle ;
\draw[olive!100, ->] (O) ++(0:16mm) arc(0:45:16mm) ;
%
\foreach \pt in {O,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H} \draw (\pt) node {$\bull$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Las ocho ra\'ices octavas de $4-4i\sqrt{3} \in \bC$}
\label{fg:eight-roots} % 1.9
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
```

However, when it compiles, it looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me, please? Thank you :)

Comment: You should remove the floating `figure` environment which is nonsense in `minipage`. To get a captioned minipage, load `caption` package and use its '\captionof{figure}{....}`.

Comment: Also please extend your code fragment to an MWE (Minimal Working Example) ...

Comment: Please, make your code fragment compilable. It is erroneous. (not defined commands, missing nodes contents, ...).

Comment: you surely get an error from figure in minipage? after any error the pdf is just a debugging aid not usable output Also remove the inter-word space between the minpages or you will not fit two on one line